# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' even though I have the module installed

Tags: python

Sorry for the badly worded title.

I installed the python module requests by using the command `pip install requests` now it worked but I opened vs code after a few days and got this error

```
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

so I used `pip uninstall requests` and then `pip install requests` it still gave me the error I am on windows 11 Visual  Studio Code python 3.10(this is happening to all modules not requests only)

Comment: vscode is likely not using the correct python environment. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: Try configuring python path in your IDE, Ctrl+Shift+P and search `select interpreter` and configure the python path

Comment: try using `python3` and `pip3` commands

Comment: I would suggest to use an `virtualenv` and activate that, so you're always sure you're using the correct python and interpreter. It also helps keep your main python install *clean*.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check the python interpreter used by vscode and ensure it's using the interpreter you installed and used by pip

Using the default interpreter from vscode, the request modules was flagged as not available and it will return an error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzmZP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZwf4.png)

Look that the button right section of vscode next to the language selector. There you will see {} python and right next to it will be the current python interpreter
Click on it and choose the correct python interpreter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKfc7.png)

Follow vscode docs to change the default interpreter so you don't have to update it everytime you open a file in your project.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#:~:text=your%20User%20Settings.-,To%20do%20so%2C%20open%20the%20Command%20Palette%20(Ctrl%2BShift,Settings%2C%20with%20the%20appropriate%20interpreter.